# Application Canadian Work Permit without LMIA

Tags: canada, working-visas

I have 8 years of IT experience and reside outside of Canada. A Canadian company is willing to offer me a job.

Should they require an LMIA to get me to Canada? Are there any options for a work permit visa(preferably open ended)?

Comment: What's your nationality?

Comment: @xngtng My nationality is Indian

Comment: Sorry, I checked back and missed the newly asked version. Can you please close this question.